# Исходники проектов

Tags: android

Здрасьте.
На каких ресурсах можно найти исходники полноценных java приложений? GIthub знаю, а какие еще...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://code.google.com/
http://sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то в стандартном Android SDK можно найти полно примеров готовых приложений.

Ищите в папке `<SDK>/samples`

---

**P.S**  Вот правда зачем копаться в исходниках целого приложения? - у авторов своя логика, которая может быть где-то непонятна( а возможно, даже и неверна ). Лучше изучайте стиль написания кода на примере отдельных сниппетов от Google.

Comment: @0xFFh,отдельные сниппеты от Google - это и есть <SDK>/samples?

Comment: Нет. То - полноценные приложения.

Comment: @0xFFh, а где искать эти сниппеты?

Answer (score 1):

[bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org)